# Single-purpose app to prevent .DS_Store creation under Mavericks

Tags: finder, macos

[Asepsis is currently not working under Mavericks](http://asepsis.binaryage.com/#faq). It's, in my knowledge, the only single-purpose app existing for this job. Therefore, what is the less intrusive solution to prevent .DS_Store creation after the update to Mavericks?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Asepsis updates have been officially released for Mavericks compatibility - http://asepsis.binaryage.com/

I've personally tested it, working like a charm!

Answer (score 4):

The free app [TinkerTool 5.0](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html), which has many functions, can be used on Mavericks to disable creating .DS_Store files on network volumes, but I do not believe this has any effect on .DS_Store files on your local Mac.

[image]

Comment: The setting can also be enabled with `defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores -bool true`, but it only disables creating .DS_Store files on network volumes.

Comment: Actually what TinkerTool does is to provide a GUI that generates many different defaults write files. It also keeps track of the ones that it creates, and it can de-install all of them using the Reset button, which puts all customizations back to their pre-TinkerTool state. This is very useful because otherwise if you create a lot of your own defaults write files, you may not remember what they all are and how to reset things back the way they were.

Answer (score 1):

[BlueHarvest](http://www.zeroonetwenty.com/blueharvest/) does not prevent the creation of .DS_Store files, but it can delete them automatically.

[image]

You can also delete .DS_Store files by using find:

```
find / -name .DS_Store -delete
```

Comment: This is actually the closest solution to what I'm looking for. However, there is a quiet important delay between the creation of a given .DS_Store file and it detection by BlueHarvest for removal. In the situation, for example, where you're a creating an archive for a windows user, this can be annoying...